# MySQL 5.5 - how can extract part of a text from a field with repetitive strings?

Tags: mysql

I have got fields like this:

```
UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>prio</name><newValue>5</newValue><oldValue>1</oldValue><newValue>aaa<oldValue>10863321</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>
UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>prio</name><newValue>51</newValue><oldValue>11</oldValue><newValue>bbb<oldValue>10863321</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>
```

and I am trying get extract text after first `<newValue>` from the left side. It will be either one or two numbers/letters. Also, at the same time I want to get first`<oldValue>` looking from left. SO the results are:

```
newValue oldValue
5        1
51       11
```

Comment: MySQL 8.0 has [REGEXP_SUBSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) but if you use 5.5, you better just fetch the whole string into your app and parse it there.

Comment: `<newValue>aaa` and `<newValue>bbb` don't have closing tag. Check [12.11 XML Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html). Try [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2asFey8mZy4obL1G3SwvD6/0).

Comment: @Kalenji is it onlya part of an XML or you have exacly what you paste here?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an incomplete XML, let's use simple string functions.

[LOCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) can find a position of a sub-string.

[LEFT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_left) gets a sub-string from the start till a position.

And from that sub-string the [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function is handy to get the characters after the final tag.

**Example code:**

```
-- test table
drop table if exists YourTable;
create table YourTable (col varchar(1000));

-- Sample data
insert into YourTable (col) values
('UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>prio</name><newValue>5</newValue><oldValue>1</oldValue><newValue>aaa<oldValue>10863321</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>'),
('UPDATE</transactionType><column> <name>prio</name><newValue>51</newValue><oldValue>11</oldValue><newValue>bbb<oldValue>10863321</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>');

-- Query
SELECT 
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(LEFT(col, LOCATE('</oldValue>', col)-1),'>',-1) AS oldValue,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(LEFT(col, LOCATE('</newValue>', col)-1),'>',-1) AS newValue
FROM YourTable;
```

**Result:**

```
oldValue    newValue
1           5
11          51
```

A test on *rextester [here](https://rextester.com/TJIMMV28675)*

**Side-note:**

In MySql 8 you could also use [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) for this.

```
SELECT  
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col,'(?<=<oldValue>)[^<>]*(?=</oldValue)',1,1) as oldValue,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col,'(?<=<newValue>)[^<>]*(?=</newValue>)',1,1) as newValue
FROM YourTable;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ea38446f6105ec0f3f657caa6fc23d4)*

*(But be silent about it. Some would frown upon you for using regex to parse XML. F.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4003419).

But then again, an invalid XML isn't really an XML)*

Answer (score 1):

As I undersand you paste only a part of your xml field. If it is a valid xml, you can use an xpath expression by function `ExtractValue`

I will provide you a simple example:

**Data definition**

```
create table Test(id integer, title varchar(2000));
insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "<a><b>X</b><b>Y</b></a>");
```

**Query**

```
select ExtractValue(title, '/a/b[1]') from Test;
```

This query returns the first element b inside tag a (note the "[1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) in the query). The result in this case is `X`.

So in your case you can use two ExtractValue functions in single query to select the first newValue tag and the first oldValue tag.

Link: [ExtractValue function in MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue)

Comment: Potential problem:  "NULL is returned if xml_frag contains elements which are not properly nested or closed, and a warning is generated..."

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not proper XML, let's try some low-level string tools.

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
'UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>prio</name><newValue>51</newValue><oldValue>11</oldValue><newValue>bbb<oldValue>10863321</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>',
                                  '</newValue>', 1),
                              '<newValue>', -1) AS x;
+----+
| x  |
+----+
| 51 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Explanation:

- The Inner SUBSTRING_INDEX gets the substring through the first `</newValue>`.
- The outer SUBSTRING_INDEX gets the text after the first `<newValue>`

Give it a try on other strings.

This should work for any MySQL version at least going back a decade.

`<oldvalue>` should work the same way, and can be a second 'column' in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` function is useful in some contexts.  For "well formed" values that contain the specified tags, we can get a useable result.  But this approach falls apart (returns potentially unexpected results) when the values aren't well formed.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(  t.foo  ,'</oldValue>',1),'<oldValue>',-1) AS first_oldValue
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(  t.foo  ,'</newValue>',1),'<newValue>',-1) AS first_newValue
  FROM ( SELECT 'UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>prio</name><newValue>5</newValue><oldValue>1</oldValue><newValue>aaa<oldValue>10863321</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>' AS foo 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>prio</name><newValue>51</newValue><oldValue>11</oldValue><newValue>bbb<oldValue>10863321</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>'
       ) t
 WHERE t.foo LIKE '%<oldValue>%</oldValue>%'
   AND t.foo LIKE '%<newValue>%</newValue>%'
```

We can incorporate the integrity checks into the expressions in the SELECT list

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.foo LIKE '%<oldValue>%</oldValue>%' THEN 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( t.foo ,'</oldValue>',1),'<oldValue>',-1)
       END AS first_oldValue
     , CASE WHEN t.foo LIKE '%<newValue>%</newValue>%' THEN
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( t.foo ,'</newValue>',1),'<newValue>',-1) 
       END AS first_newValue
  FROM ( SELECT 'UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>prio</name><newValue>5</newValue><oldValue>1</oldValue><newValue>aaa<oldValue>10863321</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>' AS foo 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>prio</name><newValue>51</newValue><oldValue>11</oldValue><newValue>bbb<oldValue>10863321</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>'
       ) t
```